# What is the event pattern called that jQuery uses for "click" and "mouseover" type events?

Tags: jquery, design-patterns

jQuery lets you call the click event like so to bind to it

```
$('#someElem').click(function() {
   console.log("Hello World");
});
```

And then jQuery also lets you invoke the event using the following.

```
$('#someElem').click();
```

Is this called the observer pattern or what is the name of this pattern?

Answer (score 2):

It's called [function overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading), about which Wikipedia says:

> It is simply defined as the ability of a single function to perform different tasks.

Some languages have "first class" support for it, allowing you to define mutiple functions with the same name but different types and/or numbers of parameters. JavaScript simulates it by inspecting the `arguments` array. In either case the function simply behaves differently depending on the number and type of arguments supplied.

It's not really a pattern, so much as it is a basic concept of programming. The [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) is something completely different.

Comment: Seems like this would have a name though. Could be the publish subscribe pattern?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish/subscribe

Comment: Actually, this is the definition of observer pattern. Seems to fit well. "[a pattern] in which an object, called the subject, maintains a list of its dependents, called observers, and notifies them automatically of any state changes, usually by calling one of their methods."

Isn't that what is happening with jQuery?

Comment: If you're talking about the actual event model, as opposed to the function overload, then it would be a stretch to call it an observer pattern. It isn't object oriented; there is no subject or observers. It's simple function-driven event-handling.

Comment: Wouldn't the object be the jQuery objects you attached an event to?